# How to serialize Object with inner PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have object PendingIntent, which was cast to String by method toString (). I need parse it to type PendingIntent. How I can do it?

This is object:

```
public class NotificationInit implements Serializable, Parcelable {
    private Bitmap app_image;
    private String title, message, time, date, noticeKey, packageName;
    private PendingIntent messageIntent;
    private Calendar notifyDate;

    public NotificationInit(String noticeKey, String packageName, Bitmap app_image, String title, String message, String time, String date, PendingIntent messageIntent) {
        this.noticeKey = noticeKey;
        this.packageName = packageName;
        this.app_image = app_image;
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
        this.time = time;
        this.date = date;
        this.messageIntent = messageIntent;

        notifyDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        notifyDate.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(time));
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeString(message);
        dest.writeString(time);
        dest.writeString(date);
        dest.writeString(noticeKey);
    }
}
```

This code also has getters and setters

I need to make it before insert into SharedPreferences, because it's easyest way to save this data without database!

How I can serialize my object?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this this way. You cannot serialize a `PendingIntent` by calling `toString()`. You cannot serialize a `PendingIntent` and save to `SharedPreferences` because the `PendingIntent` isn't persistent.

What you need to do is just store enough data so that you can **recreate** the `PendingIntent` when you need to. This means you need to know the information in the `Intent` (the ACTION, DATA, Component, etc.) and you need the `requestCode` that you passed to `PendingIntent.getActivity()`. Store those things in your `SharedPreferences`.